# Convert String to Byte Array replacing characters between specific character

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am trying to find a way to convert a string (entered into a TextBox) and convert it to a byte array to send out a serial port / socket.

I am fine with the converting string to byte[] part but am struggling a bit with the replacement

Essentially the GUI allows the user to specific the format of the response to send and I was looking at something like the following :-

User Enters : [2] Test {1} {2} [3]

{1} and {2} are variable fields which can be pulled from the incoming message so they are currently being replaced without issue.

What I am trying to achieve is replace the [2] with an STX character and the [3] with an ETX character with the 2 and 3 being their ASCII equivalents. www.asciitable.com

The user can enter any valid ascii character in this format so [13] for CR etc

Would the best way to loop through the string remembering the index of [ and then the index of ] and grab all characters between these two indexes?  Or is there a more efficient way?

Thanks,

Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression can find digits between brackets and replace them with a calculated value.
Your replacement scheme looks like it might be similar to String.Format but you'll have to compare that and decide on the order of operations and meaning of special characters.

The encoding will throw an exception if the bracketed number is outside of 0-127. You could have some other behavior if you want.

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(Encoding.ASCII.CodePage, 
    EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, 
    DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback);

var bracketRegex = new Regex(@"\[(?<digits>\d+)\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
MatchEvaluator convertToCodepoint = (match) => 
    Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse(match.Groups["digits"].Value));

var values = new[] {"a", "b", "c" };
var input = "[2] Test {1} {2} [3]";
encoding.GetBytes(String.Format(bracketRegex.Replace(input, convertToCodepoint), values))
    .Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a code similar to this:

```
string input = TextBox.text; "User name (sales)";
//Use those lines if you don't know how many times do you have to iterate.
var totalOfBraces = input.Where(x => x == '{').Count();
var totalOfBrackets = input.Where(x => x == '[').Count();
var totalOfElements = totalOfBraces + totalOfBrackets;

string output = input.Split('[', ']')[1];
string output = input.Split('{', '}')[1];
```

And you you can get the elements between Braces and Brackets and do a replace of them.

Then, why I added `totalOfElements`, to have the possibility to do a `for bucle`

For example:

```
var counterOfBraces = 0;
var counterOfBrackets = 0;
for(var i=0; i<totalOfElements.Count(); i++){
    if(i < totalOfBrackets){
        counterOfBrackets+=1;
        var textToFind = "[" + index + "]";
        input = input.Replace(textToFind, "some new text");
    } else {
        //Do the same for braces
    }

}
//NOW HERE, YOU HAVE YOUR TEXT FORMATED AND READY TO CONVERT IT TO BYTE[]
```